# MySQL ignore query of any column if null?

Tags: mysql

USERS:

```
| id | a |   b  |  c   | d |
----------------------------
|  1 | Q | NULL | NULL | X |
----------------------------
```

QUERY

```
SELECT
a AS name,
b AS job,
c AS email,
d AS phone
FROM USERS
WHERE
id='1'
AND column IS NOT NULL

//RESULT
name, phone
```

I know the `AND` statement is invalid, but I am not sure how to do it.

I have tried:

```
WHERE
a IS NOT NULL
AND b IS NOT NULL
AND c IS NOT NULL
AND d IS NOT NULL
AND id='1'
```

Failed, retuned nothing.
Also tried:

```
WHERE
name IS NOT NULL
AND job IS NOT NULL
AND email IS NOT NULL
AND phone IS NOT NULL
AND id='1'
```

Also returned nothing.
Do I need a case in the `select` portion?

Comment: Can you share the expected output? Based on that it would be easy to solve your problem

Comment: i did above, in the first example. desired output is `column a and d`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you want to return the non null values. So union the columns then group_concat

```
SELECT ID,GROUP_CONCAT(COL)
FROM
(
SELECT ID,A COL FROM T WHERE A IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT ID,B FROM T WHERE B IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT ID,C FROM T WHERE C IS NOT NULL
UNION ALL
SELECT ID,D FROM T WHERE D IS NOT NULL
) S
group by id
```

Comment: does this cause a lot of performance delay? would it be faster to query the result, even null values, then use php to remove the null values?

Comment: mysql tag mysql answer - if you want php solutions you should tag php too.

Comment: i dont necessarily. just a quick question. remove data in query VS after query. what would the performance delay be of a 50 column query? vs just a regular select, null or not

Comment: Personally I favour array processing over table processing but I'm not on a position to test over a 50 cols.